# How to change language of Dynamic Android App?

Tags: android, mysql, dynamic, localization

I want to setup language switcher for android app which is complete build already, i want solution for localizing android dynamic app.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN)` it loads German as default locale in your app.  You can select any locale that you want and your device supports.